# How to make OS X not remember ssh key passphrase

Tags: macos, ssh

I have a passphrase on my ssh id_rsa key, and OS X  asks me for the passphrase the *first* time I want to use it, but even if I decline to add it to my keychain, it doesn't ask me for a passphrase again until I reboot. How can I make it ask me for a passphrase *every* time I try to use it?

Comment: Have you tried fully closing out your Terminal session?

Comment: yup that doesn't work. only thing that works is logging out as the user altogether. Maybe theres a command i can type into the terminal to tell it to forget the passphrase?

Comment: how do you " decline to add it to my keychain,"? What does `ssh-add -l` prints after the first use? And what about `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`?

Answer (score 2):

While reading [GitHub documentation about adding ssh key to the ssh agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent), I thought you might be able to prevent loading keys in the agent by modifying the `~/.ssh/config` file like so:

```
Host *
 AddKeysToAgent no
 UseKeychain no
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute following command in Termina.app will disable Keychain integration, thus ssh will *always* ask you for a passphrase:

```
defaults write org.openbsd.openssh KeychainIntegration -bool false
```

Pleases note:

1. This is undocumented, but as far as I know, it works from macOS 10.6 (Snow Leopard) to 10.11 (El Capitan)
2. It will affect all private keys, not just `id_rsa`
3. Set the value to `true` if you want to recover the default behavior
4. Kill `ssh-agent` process or restart your Mac if it has no effect after executing the command

Comment: its still remembering the passphrase unfortunately, even after doing this. I'm on Sierra now but it was still happening even with El Capitan...

Comment: @MohamedHafez Maybe go into the Keychain app and delete the entry? (just search for ssh)